# How can I write a script to monitor changes in database? ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES Error

Tags: python, django, database

I am using Django and have a skeleton website with a single button that increments an IntegerField in my database. I want to have an external script which continually reads this IntegerField and reports when a change has been made.

models.py

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    ctr = Counter.objects.get(id=1)
    pre = ctr.count
    print(f"pre: {pre}")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get("increment"):
            Counter.objects.filter(id=1).update(count=F('count') + 1)
            post = ctr.count
            print(f"pre: {pre}")


return render(request, 'increment.html')
```

I thought I could simply achieve this inside the view function but I've had difficulty detecting a change because the pre & post values above are the same when I print them even though post is clearly created after the field is incremented.

I have a watcher.py file inside my app directory where I am trying to program a script that would run in the background and report changes to the database. Here's what I have so far:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True)

import django
django.setup()

import models
import time
from ahelper import settings
from threading import Thread


def watcher():
    ctr = models.Counter.objects.get(id=1)
    pre = ctr.count
    print(f"{pre}")
    print("start loop")
    while (1):
        temp = time.time()
        post = ctr.count
        if pre != post:
            print("Change detected")
            response_time = (time.time() - temp) * 1000
            print(f"{response_time}ms")

watcher()
```

When I try to run this, I get the error: **ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details**. I don't understand why this comes up and I don't know how to resolve it; The engine value is provided in the settings file already.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
 }
}
```

I am very lost at this point so any help is appreciated. Am I going about this the right way? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: How is the watcher module supposed to run ? Does it get served by any API endpoint ? Or you are like just importing it somewhere ? Can you you share more information on why you re trying to track this value in the database ? Doe this logic need to happen in Django or should it maybe done in an separate app that calls the Django API ?

Comment: Hey, I am fairly new to this so I don't know the best way to go about it, but I was thinking of running watcher in a seperate thread inside the terminal in VSCode. I have ultimately been tasked to have an external program/script to monitor the database and report the time it takes to overwrite the value. Let me know if this info is of any help

Answer (score 0):

You must run this script in a django app. This could be done in different manner, but a way more simple one would be to use the before/post save signal of Django, so you know when this field is modified: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

If you still want to use a dedicated runner, you can create a thread/process that run aside Django. Still you have one issue in your code,

```
post = ctr.count
```

This will not reload the object state from the database. You need to reload the object manually to ensure it is uptodate. Other way you would not detect any changes:

```
ctr.refresh_from_db()
post = ctr.count
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would like to run the watcher function in a seperate thread to do so. However, I get the aferomentioned error when trying to run that file. Any ideas on how I may fix it?

Comment: How do you launch your file ?

Comment: Through the terminal within vscode

Comment: I guess you must load you django.setup() after passing all settings. Look at https://abdus.dev/posts/django-orm-standalone/ for instance (he passes all args).
Otherwise I guess your INSTALLED_APP is empty.

Comment: I've been able to get it to work by defining meta data in my model and setting an app_label, however the script still doesn't seem to work. I don't get errors anymore, I just don't get anything, not even a print statement when I run the file. I don't know whats wrong. Also in terms of using signals, I was afraid they may not work for me because I am not using save() to make changes to the database so not sure if it would work, but I'll check it out.

Comment: How do you save data if you don't use save() ?

Comment: in my views file I have Counter.objects.filter(id=1).update(count=F('count') + 1) which increments the value without needing to use save()

Comment: Ah ok, so yeah signals will not work on that.